# Overriding default exception message in PHP

Tags: php

I have a class with exceptions and I want a default Exception if the exception is not caught outside the class.

Here's some code:

```
<?php


Class Test
{
    public $file;


    public function setFile($file)
    {
        $this->file = $file;
    }

    public function getFile()
    {
        return $this->file;
    }

    public function test()
    {
        try
        {

            return $this->getFile();

            if($this->getFile() == "test")
            {
                throw new TestException("The variable is test!");
            }
        }
        catch (TestException $e)
        {
            return "Default exception message: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}

class TestException extends \Exception
{

    public function __construct($message)
    {
        parent::__construct($message);
    }
}

 $t = new Test;
 $t->setFile('test');
try {
    echo $t->test();
}
catch(TestException $e) {
   //this wont do anything
   return "I want to overwrite exception here... " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Furthermore, not using the try block with catch will just throw an uncaught exception error.

So is there a way to override the handling? The most obvious way is to throw an error within the class, remove the try block, and catch the exception outside of the class, but I'm wondering if there's a way to override.

Answer (score 1):

If you want what I think you want. One solution is to use set_exception_handler : http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php.

This means you can remove the try-catch block and any uncaught exceptions will end up in the function you gave to set_exception_handler().

There's no scoping for the exception handler though so this will be application wide behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You can say function don`t catch Eexception if pass some additional argument.

```
public function test(is_throw_exception=False)
    {
        try
        {
           . . .
        }
        catch (TestException $e)
        {
            if is_throw_exception {
               throw new TestException("The variable is test!");
            }
            return "Default exception message: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```